# How can I move the collapse button to the bottom upon clicking?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap to create a card that can be expanded on click. For this, I am using collapse. But when I use collapse the button stays put, whereas I want it to move to the bottom of the card. The pictures at the bottom should also illustrate quite clearly what, I am attempting to do.

How can I move the button down when clicking collapse? Will I have to use Javascript?

Thanks for reading this

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2">
      <!-- horizontal spacing -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-8 ">
    <div class="card text">
      <div class="card-header">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="text-primary"> Name Nameson </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <!-- horizontal spacing -->
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="float-right text-secondary"> Aug 21 2019 </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Average Rating (4.5) </h5>
        <p class="card-text">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not </p>

      </div>
      <div class="card-footer text-muted text-center">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#review">
          <div class="row">
          <div> Click to see full review </div>
          </div>
          <span class="oi oi-caret-bottom"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="review">
          Content goes here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Before collapse]

[image: After collapse]

Comment: Just keep your collapsible div above your anchor

Comment: For people who are looking for doing something similar (collapse button at the end): you should also know that you are triggering your users. When the user clicks the expand button, most of the times he instantly regrets when 2 - 3 pages worth of content is displayed, so they want to collapse and skip the content immediately. Having the collapse button at the end forces the user to scroll in pain. Not to mention that sometimes, after clicking <collapse>, it will not redirect you up again in page, so you have to again scroll up to resume the initial content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the additional content into a single `collapse` div above the card-footer...

https://codeply.com/p/R3QbJnLQDE

```
         <div class="card text">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="text-primary"> Name Nameson </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <!-- horizontal spacing -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <div class="float-right text-secondary"> Aug 21 2019 </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Average Rating (4.5) </h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not </p>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse" id="review">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">More </h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not </p>
                    </div>
                    ... (additional content sections here)
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#review">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div> Click to see full review </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="oi oi-caret-bottom"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need to restructure you DIVs, in where to sperate what you need to show initiative and onClick event show more...

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <!-- horizontal spacing -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 ">
      <div class="card text">
        <div class="card-header">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="text-primary"> Name Nameson </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <!-- horizontal spacing -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="float-right text-secondary"> Aug 21 2019 </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="inital">
            <h5 class="card-title">Average Rating (4.5) </h5>
            <p class="card-text">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not </p>
          </div>
          <div class="ondemand">
            <div class="section">
              <h5 class="card-title">Average Rating (4.5) </h5>
              <p>Be sure to have your pages set up with the latest design and development standards. That means using an HTML5 doctype and including a viewport meta tag for proper responsive behaviors. Put it all together and your pages should look like this</p>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
              <h5 class="card-title">Average Rating (4.5) </h5>
              <p>Be sure to have your pages set up with the latest design and development standards. That means using an HTML5 doctype and including a viewport meta tag for proper responsive behaviors. Put it all together and your pages should look like this</p>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
              <h5 class="card-title">Average Rating (4.5) </h5>
              <p>Be sure to have your pages set up with the latest design and development standards. That means using an HTML5 doctype and including a viewport meta tag for proper responsive behaviors. Put it all together and your pages should look like this</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted text-center">
          <a href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#review">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="showmore">Load more</div>
              <div class="showless">Show Less</div>
            </div>
            <span class="oi oi-caret-bottom"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="collapse" id="review">
            Content goes here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS: Jquery -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.ondemand').hide();
  $('.showmore').show();
  $('.showless').hide();

  $('.showmore').on('click', function(){
    $('.ondemand').slideDown("slow", "swing");
    $('.showmore').hide();
    $('.showless').show();
  });

  $('.showless').on('click', function(){
    $('.ondemand').slideUp("slow", "swing");
    $('.showmore').show();
    $('.showless').hide();
  });


});
```

Here is demo: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/foavdtzk/12/)